# VueJs Watch per key of a model

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an object (model), as an input field,for a search method, and I want that the watcher to detect changes per key, and not for all.

Right now ,if an input is changed, the watcher is called 10 times  (the number of inputs that I have).

```
<b-form-input
        v-model="search[field.column]"
        type="search"
        id="filterInput"
        placeholder="search.."
></b-form-input>

watch:{
search: {
    handler(){
        // do somenthing
    },
    deep: true
}
}
```

Comment: You can watch the key explicitly ie. `search[field.column]` instead of deep watching the entire object as demonstrated in the below answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can watch a computed value that return the specific field that you want to watch.

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    form: {
      name : '',
      lastname: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    formName() {
      return this.form.name;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    formName() {
      console.log("Name has changed")
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Name : 
  <input v-model="form.name" />
  Lastname : 
  <input v-model="form.lastname" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can explicitly watch the required key only.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    search: {
      name: { placeholder: 'search name', value: '' },
      age: { placeholder: 'search age', value: '' },
      country: { placeholder: 'search country', value: '' }
    }
  },

  watch:{
    'search.name.value': { // Explicitly watch the required key.
        handler(){
            console.log('name changed...')
        }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

   <form>
    <input
      v-for="(value, key, i) in search"
      :key="i"
      v-model="search[key].value"
      type="search"
      id="filterInput"
      :placeholder="value.placeholder"
    /> 
   </form>
 
 </div>
```

*So, here watch's handler is called only when the name is searched & does not get called when age or country is searched.*